# Accessing my list field values via dot notation after json.stringifier

Tags: json, client-object-model

This just be so obvious but I it seems not. Below I stripped out some of the code for clarity

```
 var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('SMenuLink')

 //usual code to open a list using CSOM

 context.load(allItems,"Include(Title,SubMenuItemId,SubMenuItemText)
  //a array to hold our JSon stringifer objects
  var subMenuItems = [];

 // loop through the list
 {
    var subMenuItem = JSON.stringify(listItem.get_fieldValues());

    // create a Json Object with sringifier
    subMenuItems.push(subMenuItem)

 }
```

Now I want to reference the one of the array items and pick the field value

```
  var daniel = subMenuItems[0].SubMenuItemText;
  alert(daniel);
```

I can see that array item [0] looks perfect in firebug but I not for the first time in my life  am still "undefined"!!!! Therefore, my syntax is obviously wrong.....

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Client API expert by any means, but does get_fieldValues() get JUST the field values?

I thought it would store an object like:
{"Title":"Task 1","SubMenuItemId":"1","SubMenuItemText":"My funcky text"}

Maybe you need to seperate the field title and field value in your "var daniel = subMenuItems[0].SubMenuItemText;" line?

Just a thought,

Mark

Comment: Mark I think you are on the right lines and yes the object array as seen in firebug looks exactly like you have depicted. It will be something like  subMenuItems.somthng[0].SubMenuItemText;

Comment: Mark, Jimmy and Alex.... After a bit of time staring blankly at FF ... It dawned on my that I was just dealing an array of strings in json format and not objects.  Tried every thing I could think of to instanstiate the json on object with a {} syntax..all I acheived was a headache and multiple FF crashes. Then after a bit of googling I spotted this http://www.devcurry.com/2010/12/resolve-json-is-undefined-error-in.html . Thereafter, the answer was obvious

Comment: var daniel = JSON.parse(subMenuItems[0]);
           
      daniel.subMenuItemText;   // at last I am not undefined!!!